# How to reference a UILabel that was added through code so I can update position when iPad is rotated?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I added a UILabel subview using code. When the user rotates the iPad, I want to be able to tell that UILabel to shift its position to accomodate the new screen orientation.

I think I need to put my code in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation function.
I want to be able to get at my UILabel and I see sample code that looks like the following to retrieve a reference to a subview:
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *) [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

How do I know what index my UILabel is at? The sample code seems to know that their subview is the first one (index 0).

Is there a way for me to find out what my UILabel's index is?

Is there another way to keep a reference to this UILabel that I create in code? If I made myLabel a variable of the class, will I be able to reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in your UIViewController, you'd have an instance variable that was a pointer to your UILabel. Then you can access it anywhere in your controller's code.

Answer (score 0):

Either have it in an instance variable (I like this, because it allows you to give nice names to your views), or set its `tag` property so you can find it again via `[self.view viewWithTag:myTag]` (the tag is just a number you assign to the view for exactly the purpose of finding it later).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility is not to do this, but instead set an `autoresizingMask` so it (for example) sticks to the upper left corner.